# Distinguish between schema and database

Tags: postgresql, schema, plpgsql

I had the error `cross-database references are not implemented: scan.location.alias` with this PL/pgSQL code:

```
DECLARE
    v_tmp_host scan.location.alias%TYPE;
    v_ip_address character varying;
BEGIN
    -- Some assignment to v_ip_address

    v_tmp_host := v_ip_address::scan.location.alias%TYPE;
```

Since the code was working for a long time, I investigated and found out, that "scan" is a schema in the database this trigger exists in **and** someone created a database called "scan" some days ago. Since now "scan" is a db as well as a schema, pg seems to use the db instead of the schema.

My question is, how can I avoid such problems in future? How should I write this code to don't get broken by creating additional relations, databases or schemas?

Or in other words: How can I force pg to use the schema and not the db in this situation?

Comment: Are there other `location` tables in other schemas?

Comment: No, in this situation the table only exists once.

Comment: After more testing, I could not make %TYPE work in assignment in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your variable as the desired type.  The `%TYPE` construct is for copying types, therefore it is usable in the [`DECLARE` section](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-TYPE) only.  In return, the assignment will be simpler:

```
DECLARE
    v_tmp_host scan.location.alias%TYPE;
    v_ip_address character varying;
BEGIN
    v_ip_address := '127.0.0.1';
    v_tmp_host := v_ip_address;
    [...]
```

The only change to your code is that I completely omitted the cast from the assignment.  In this case, PostgreSQL won't try to resolve `scan` as a database name, since cross-database references are not implemented...

If you declared your variable with a certain type, assignments will try to cast the given value to that type.  In case of failure you'll get an error.  Since normal `inet` input is just a single-quoted string, a `varchar` will be accepted (if its format fits the `inet` input format).

Comment: My problem is in the assign statement. I need to cast the `'127.0.0.1'` to the type of the `alias` column.

Comment: @ManuelFaux If you declared your variable with a certain type, assignments will try to cast the given value to that type.  In case of failure you'll get an error.

Comment: In this case the type is inet, so a implicit cast from `'127.0.0.1'` to inet is not possible. I tried to do an explicit cast with the code I've posted in my question, which worked as long as the table "scan" did not exist.

Comment: I run a quick test on 9.1, it worked.  Since normal `inet` input is just a single-quoted string, it should work.  Have you tried it?

Comment: You are right! Okay, the example in my question was really a bad choice, in contrast what I wanted to ask. I will redefine it.

Comment: @ManuelFaux I wonder how could it ever work, normally you _should_ get the error you finally got.  What's your PG version?

Comment: You are right, again! It seems as this part of the trigger was never called, since it's only checked during execution and not during compilation. Is there a way to use this kind of syntax in any way? Since during compilation no error is raised, I think there as to be a use of this...

Comment: @ManuelFaux As I've already noticed above, I couldn't make it work.  Without schema name it throws an other error, with it nor cross-reference.  Furthermore, while it isn't mentioned explicitely int the docs, it is clear that %TYPE serves as a tool for declarations, not assignments.  Compiling plpgsql functions does not reveal all errors (some are thrown only when running them), and it is quite possible that `check_function_bodies` was set to `off` at compile time.

Comment: Okay, thank's for your help and explanation.